# What is the proper way to calculate post counters with MongoDB based application?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm building forum with questions and answers like SO. My database is MongoDB and my question is how to properly store and calculate counters related to post?

For example I have two collections:

**Posts:**

```
[{
   _id: ObjectId(1),
   title: 'Untitled',
   content: 'empty'
}]
```

**Votes:**

```
[{ 
    _post: ObjectId(1),
    _user: ObjectId(...),
    vote: 1,        
}, {
    _post: ObjectId(1),
    _user: ObjectId(...),
    vote: 1,
}]
```

When user vote to post with `ObjectId(1)` he issues the following query:

```
Votes.create({_post: ObjectId(1), vote: 1}).exec(cb);
```

All seem looks fine but when I need to fetch chunk of last 100 posts I get performance issues. The thing is I need to:

1. Query chunk of posts
2. Query all votes for all posts and merge them by hand.

I want to fix performance issues and in Post schema additional field for counting votes:

```
[{
   _id: ObjectId(1),
   title: 'Untitled',
   content: 'empty',
   votes: 2
}]
```

But in this case I heed to somehow support consistency and atomic update Post votes when new vote get created in Votes collection.

Could you advice best practices to support consistency between Posts and Votes collection?

Thanks!

**I know that I can use embedding and store votes array within Posts but I don't want because my posts may grow and I may stick with another performance issues**

Comment: You probably don't care too much about being absolutely consistent. If cached votes count is off by 1, who cares? it's not a financial transaction. That being said, creating the vote record and then `$inc`-ing `votes_up` field in the post should be consistent, unless your db crashes in between queries, which should be rare.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I agree with you that it's not critical but I want to know how to make it in proper way.

Comment: Erik, you see, the proper thing would be to use a database which supports transactions. :) And here you can't do much better than described above. For the peace of mind, you could run a nightly job (or something) that will recalculate cached counters from raw data. Track the stats and see how often this job will find and fix inconsistencies. Decide if you want to keep the job.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev that is interesting thing using jobs. I need to think about it. Thanks for the advice :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [simple voting system with MongoDB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12339233/simple-voting-system-with-mongodb)

Comment: That solution does't useful for me as I point this in my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As many would suggest, NoSQL isn't the nicest to work with when inter-model relationships become important; that said, let's attempt to list down your two important business goals:

- High performance querying of posts for vote-counts
- Atomic or concurrency-safe / accuracy is important to you

Of course, you're on the right track with caching the count - but if accuracy is important to you, then I'd do two things:

1. Instead of incrementing or decrementing the cached `votes` field directly, populate it with a query on an appropriately indexed `Votes` collection
2. Use `createdAt` and `updatedAt` style time-stamps to ensure that the cached result is only replaced by a computed value later in time from the previous one :) Yes, it isn't atomic, but it sure helps to ensure that only the most relevant value (measured by milliseconds of precision) is cached

Now, if you want to go the full mile of course, the appropriate thing to do would be to have a singular service that runs not unlike a cron every few moments, targeting only those with newer `updatedAt`s. An intelligently done (2) should, however, make this unnecessary.

Hope this helps!

**Example**

`Posts`

> _id: "f00b4r", data: {...}, votes: 0, createdAt: "2016-05-23T07:27:33.043Z", updatedAt: "2016-05-23T07:27:33.043Z"

Now, a user hits a **down-vote** so here's what happens:

`Votes`

> _id: "sn4fuu", user_id: "j0hnd03" post_id: "f00b4r", value: -1, createdAt: "2016-05-23T07:28:33.043Z", updatedAt: "2016-05-23T07:28:33.043Z"

Our code (say NodeJS) now also triggers a query across all `Votes` for `post_id: f00b4r` (an indexed field, for speed!), that gives a value count of `-1`.

We save this programmatically so that `Posts` now looks like this:

> _id: "f00b4r", data: {...}, votes: -1, createdAt: "2016-05-23T07:27:33.043Z", updatedAt: "2016-05-23T07:28:33.043Z"

**Notice the `updatedAt` has gone from 07:27 to 07:28!**

We populate the `updatedAt` on `Posts` with the latest `updatedAt` found in the `Votes` collection for it, to ensure only the latest update results in the finally cached vote-count (yes, you're right in thinking you'll need an index here too)! If our code finds a newer `updatedAt` than what it is about to save, it realises it has outdated information and does NOT dirty-write it!

Now if the user changes his **down-vote** to an **up-vote**:

`Votes`

> _id: "sn4fuu", user_id: "j0hnd03" post_id: "f00b4r", value: 1, createdAt: "2016-05-23T07:28:33.043Z", updatedAt: "2016-05-23T07:29:33.043Z"

`Posts`

> _id: "f00b4r", data: {...}, votes: 1, createdAt: "2016-05-23T07:27:33.043Z", updatedAt: "2016-05-23T07:29:33.043Z"

Since we query `Votes` every time, we get legal values for sophisticated scenarios such as this as well, since we don't simply increment or decrement the cache directly.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Could you provide any code example for your first suggestion? I'm don't understand a little bit.

Comment: @Erik have updated with a storyline - does this help? The code itself for Mongo should be fairly trivial

Comment: looks interesting but I don't undersctand this: `Our code (say NodeJS) now also triggers a query across all Votes for post_id: f00b4r (an indexed field, for speed!), that gives a value count of -1`. We need to get all votes for `post_id: f00b4r` or just the last with `_id: "sn4fuu"`?

Comment: @Erik We must retrieve all votes, it's the only way to enable storing each user's actions independently. However, it's not slow as you'd think it to be - an Index on `post_id` and `updatedAt` of `Votes` will let you do everything above efficiently. In fact, you can also use `$sum` instead of  having to total vote values yourself in Node :) https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/

Comment: Oh, I undersstand now. But if we need to get all votes to calculate `total count` what vote's `updatedAt` you use to update post's `updatedAt`? I mean where you point to `Notice the updatedAt has gone from 07:27 to 07:28!`

Comment: @Erik `$max` of `Votes`' `updatedAt`. Latest action as of running the query, to ensure its results are the latest https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/max/

Using `new Date().toISOString()` to generate these, so that a simple String comparison works due to how the chars are ordered

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112655/discussion-between-erik-and-angad).

Comment: whay should we use `$max` date? Could we use just `Date.now()` ?

Answer (score -2):

Votes:

```
[{ 
    _post: ObjectId(1),
    _user: [ObjectId(...),ObjectId(...),ObjectId(...),ObjectId(...)],       
}, {
    _post: ObjectId(2),
    _user: [ObjectId(...),ObjectId(...),ObjectId(...),ObjectId(...)],
}]
```

Comment: So? How it would help me?